# How do I replace import sys sys.path.append('./') from all my imports

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I am using Vscode and every time I want to import a package from the current working directory, I need to have the following import at the top before importing my own module.

```py
import sys
sys.path.append('./')
```

For example, my folder is:

```
My-Project
  folder1:
    - main.py
  folder2:
    - fun.py
```

main.py

```
import sys
sys.path.append('./')
from folder2 import fun
```

My question is how do I get rid of the `import sys` from the code?

Comment: Are folder1 and folder2 in the same folder?

Comment: yes thery are, i will update my question to make it clearer

Comment: Is `main.py` in folder1?

Comment: yes main.py is in folder1

Comment: The real question is: why do you *want* to do that in the first place? Importing from a well-known path is error prone enough; importing from the current working directory is unstable by design.

Comment: if i dont have the import it just doesn't work, I get an import not found error

Comment: What doesn't work? How do you run this? Does `python3 My-Project/folder1/main.py` work (well, fail) as desired?

Comment: I am using vscode code runner and it gives me a modulenotfound error

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that in VS Code, when importing other files in a file, it searches from the parent folder of the current file by default (for example: folder2 cannot be found in the file folder1). Therefore, the terminal displays that the folder cannot be found.

Since you don't want to use code to solve this problem, here is a method and you could refer to it.

Please use the debugging function of VS Code and add the following settings in "launch.json", which will add the project path to the system path when debugging:

```
"env": {
                "PYTHONPATH": "${workspaceFolder}",
            }
```

Then click `F5` or "`Start Debugging`":

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. Is this only going to work if I debug my code everytime I want to run it?

Comment: @Little Ball -Yes, "launch.json" is for setting up code debugging. For run the code, we need to add the code at the beginning to add the file path to the system path for VS Code to find it.